# two problems on Sylow's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

1. How many elements of order $5$ does a non-cyclic group of order $55$ have?
2. Let $G$ be a group of order $105$. Show that $G$ has a subgroup of order $35$.

---

1. By Sylow's theorem it has two subgroups of order $5$. But after that I could not proceed.
2. By Cauchy's theorem it has a subgroup of order $5$ (name it by $H$) and a subgroup of order $7$ (name it by $K$). Then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ and has order $35$. Am I right?

Comment: an element of order 5 generates a subgroup of order 5, so any element of order 5 must lie in some subgroup of order 5. And what are those elements in a subgroup of order 5 that is in fact of order 5?

Comment: each group of order 5 has 4 elements of order 5.then what should be answer?Is It 4+4=8

Comment: No. It has more than two subgroups of order 5.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 2. It is right if $H$ or $K$ is normal. If $H$ is not normal then $G$ contains 21 Sylow 5-subgroups. Since intersection of every two of them is $1$ then it is not enough space for Sylow 7-subgroups.

Comment: still not get it how to solve?

Comment: There is $21\cdot 4=84$ elements of order 5 and the unity element. Hence it remains 20 elements in $G$. Therefore $G$ contains only one Sylow 7-subgroup and it is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$\;\color{red}{(1)}\;$

(i) A group of order a prime $\,p\,$ has $\,p-1\,$ elements of order $\,p\,$

(ii)  The number $\,n_p\,$ of Sylow $\,p$-subgroups in a finite group $\,G\,$ of order $\,p^nm\;,\;\;(p,m)=1\;$ , always fulfills

$$n_p=1\pmod p\;,\;\;n_p\mid\frac{|G|}{p^n}\;$$

$\;\color{red}{(2)}\;$

(i) If we have two subgroups $\,H,K\le G\;$ , then $\;HK\le G\iff HK=KH\;$

(ii) If $\,H\le G\;,\;N\lhd G\;$ , then $\,HN=NH\;$

(iii) $\;105=3\cdot5\cdot 7\;$ , so

$$n_5=21\implies 84\;\;\text{elements of order}\;\;5\\n_7=15\implies 90\;\;\text{elements of order}\;\;7$$

*thus:* there is either a unique Sylow $\,5$-subgroup or a unique $\,7$-subgroup

**General:** A Sylow $\,p$-subgroup is normal iff $\,n_p=1\;$